# D7: Read var-arguments after call proc with asm 32-bit stdcall

Tags: delphi, dll, x86, inline-assembly, function-call

Hello using code below to call a function with asm and after call read the result. That works fine. Now,- how to read the argument changes afterwards, best regards

```
//push arguments:
  for i:=lst.cnt downto 0 do begin //reverse order
   ia:=longword(lst.fList^[i]);
   asm push ia end;   //push 32-Bit argument
  end;
  asm
   call proc     //call the routine
   mov ia, eax   //get result right after the call
  end;
//how to read variable arguments here ?
```

edit:

The initial code has run for some time without any issues, even when using the loop. The reason for this question came, when i had to call a winapi routine like this:

```
function GetWindowRect(hWnd: HWND; var lpRect: TRect): BOOL; stdcall;
external user32 name 'GetWindowRect';
```

It has declared a variable record argument "lpRect" (size: 16 bytes). I was trying to (push) these 4 integers before call, and then read them after call. Turns out **just passing a pointer** to the data actually worked in this case.

Conclusion: So there is no such thing variable arguments, only pointers to value or record. Thanks for any inputs helped getting to this conclusion

Comment: "ia" contains the result (which works), would like to read all the argument passed before call with "push" if they are changed by the procedure

Comment: Depending on the calling convention STDCALL they may still be on the stack. Try `mov ecx, [esp-4]` and `mov ecx, [esp-8]` and so on to retrieve the former parameters.

Comment: Your code works by chance. Using "push" asm within a loop is very risky. And it depends on the calling convention... `proc` can't be a regular Delphi function with register calling convention.

Comment: @zx485 thanks a lot will try to do that, be returning.

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez yes always using stdcall for now (dll) to call winapi and parameters are well prepared before the loop. Had to use the loop because the input number of arguments can vary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass the parameters by value, then `list.fList^[i]` contains the pointer to the value.

Just unreference and use it, for instance `PInteger(list.fList^[i])^` for an integer parameter passed by reference (as `var`).

But note that your code is pretty awful, and using push within the loop is very risky. It would also need to follow the calling convention - a `proc`  function defined with default Delphi register passes its first parameters into eax/ecx/edx. Check [this reference material](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions) - your question seems to indicate that you are a bit confused with how it works.